# How to have an effect wait on an Observable with @ngrx/effects

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am using @ngrx/effects in my Angular 2 application and I'm having some issues trying to implement an effect that is dependent on a condition based on the state of the application.

In my state, I have a map of Location -> Capabilities, keyed by `locationId` (as well as other maps of Location -> *).  When `ACTION_A` occurs, I only want it proceed once there are capabilities that are up-to-date for the current location.  When `ACTION_A` is dispatched, the capabilities *may* already be up-to-date, however, the application could also be in the process of loading new ones.

With the code below, once `ACTION_A` is dispatched once, `isOutOfDate` is called every time *any* action is dispatched to the store.  So, it seems like the observable is still active, even after the up-to-date filter has been met.  However, if `getCapabilities` is replaced with `getCapabilitiesWorking`, then `isOutOfDate` is only called until the filter condition is met each time the `ACTION_A` action is dispatched, as I would expect from either implementation.

So, it seems like I am missing something with how `combineLatest` or `filter` or `take` works ...

or perhaps I am approaching this all wrong ...

I would rather be able to use the common function for my 'current location' selectors

Any ideas?

```js
@Effect() route$ = actions$
    .ofType(ACTION_A)
    .switchMap(() => this._store.let(getCapabilities)
        .filter(capabilities => !isOutOfDate(capabilities))
        .take(1)
    )
    .map( do some stuff );

// Selector function that causes excess observable emits
export const getCapabilities =
     compose(fromLocations.currentLocationLookup(fromLocations.getCapabilities), fromRoot.getLocations);

// Selector function works as expected
export const getCapabilitiesWorking = function (state$: Observable<AppState>): Observable<Capability> {
    return state$
        .let(fromRoot.getLocations)
        .map(l => l.capabilitiesByLocation[l.currentId]);
};

// fromLocations
// -------------

export function getCapabilities(state$: Observable<LocationsState>): Observable<{ [id: string]: Capability }> {
    return state$.map(s => s.capabilitiesByLocation);
}

// Find the value in 'collection' corresponding to the current location
export function currentLocationLookup<T>(
    collection: (state$: Observable<LocationsState>) => Observable<{ [id: string]: T }>
): (state$: Observable<LocationsState>) => Observable<T> {
    return (state$: Observable<LocationsState>): Observable<T> => {
        return Observable.combineLatest(
            state$.let(getCurrentLocation),
            state$.let(collection),
            (locId, map) => map[locId]
        );
    };
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, the `isOutOfDate` function keeps getting invoked, however the "do some stuff" does not...

Answer (score 8):

You might try to replace the filter in the switchMap with [skipWhile](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipUntil)

So the Effect will be:

```
@Effect() route$ = actions$
.ofType(ACTION_A)
.switchMap(() => this._store.let(getCapabilities)
    .skipWhile(capabilities => !isOutOfDate(capabilities))
    .take(1)
)
.map( do some stuff );
```

This helped me in a similar use case :)

Comment: If waiting on another Observable, use `skipUntil`. `skipWhile` tests a condition based upon the source observable.

Answer (score 6):

`withLatestFrom` won't work, since resulted observable will emit the output only when source emits(action dispatched), in accordance with doc you need [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest), so:

```
@Effect() route$ = actions$
  .ofType(ACTION_A)
  .combineLatest(this._store.let(getCapabilities))
  .filter(([action, capabilities]) =>!isOutOfDate(capabilities)) 
  .map( do some stuff );
```

Comment: This is not considered best practice, at least as of today.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [withLatestFrom](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md) method. Your effect can look like

```
@Effect() route$ = actions$
.ofType(ACTION_A)
.withLatestFrom(this._store.let(getCapabilities))
.filter(([action, capabilities]) =>!isOutOfDate(capabilities)) 
.map( do some stuff );
```

Comment: I considered that possibility, however, it's not quite what I need.  It will take whatever the current value is in the store, which may not have been populated yet.  Then the filter gets applied at the wrong point.  I need it to 'wait' until capabilities is populated, then have the effect 'do some stuff'